# How to avoid instanceof check in Java

Tags: java, instanceof, visitor-pattern

I have the following class structure:

```
class Thing {
}

abstract class Pet extends Thing {
    void eat(Thing thing) {
       // do something
    }
}

class Tiger extends Pet {
    void eat(Thing thing) {
        if (thing instanceOf Creature)
             // do Something
        else
             super.eat(thing);
    }
}
```

I want to avoid instance of check from subclass `Tiger`? Is there any way to achieve this? How can I replace this using visitor pattern?

`Thing` is a base class.
`Pet` is an abstract class which has method `eat()`.
Subclass `Tiger` wants a specific implementation for eat method.

Answer (score 2):

Try this solution using `Map`:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;

interface ToDo {
  void exec();
}

abstract class Animal {}

class Tiger extends Animal {}

class Dog extends Animal {}

class Ideone {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map <Class, ToDo> map = new HashMap <Class, ToDo>();
    map.put(Tiger.class, new ToDo() {
        public void exec() {
            System.out.println("do for tiger ...");
        }
    });
    map.put(Dog.class, new ToDo() {
        public void exec() {
            System.out.println("do for dog ...");
        }
    });
    for(Animal a : new Animal[]{new Tiger(), new Dog(), null}) {
        try {
            map.get(a.getClass()).exec();
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            System.out.println("nothing to do ...");
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several solutions:

1. Move the check to Thing: `if (thing.isEatable())`
2. Let thing throw an exception if not eatable: `try { eat(thing); } catch …`
3. Don't assume that all pets can eat things. Remove the `eat(Thing)` method from pet, and add a `eat(Creature)` or `eat(Food)` method to `Tiger`.
4. Move the logic to the `Thing`. Call `thing.beingEaten()`, and override that method in `Creature` to call `doSomething` instead of `eat`.

Edit:

How to call `doOneThing()` only if the thing is a `Creature`:

**With instanceof:**

```
class Tiger extends Pet {
    void eat (Thing thing) {
        if (thing is instanceOf Creature) {
            doOneThing();
        } else {
            doOtherThing();
        }
    }
}
```

**Without instanceof:**

```
class Tiger extends Pet {
    void eat(Thing thing) {
        thing.beEaten();
    }
}

class Creature extends Thing {
    void beEaten() {
        doOneThing();
    }
}

class Thing {
    void beEaten() {
        doOtherThing();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. please have a look at my answer posted below

Comment: The second approach doesn't make sense, IMO. The action of eating has more of a relationship to the "eater" than the "eaten"; e.g. we say "I ate the apple" rather than "The apple was eaten by me". Also, different creatures have different diets... and so one universal response per food would not suffice.